# Create multiple Spark DataFrames from RDD based on some key value (pyspark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have some text files containing JSON objects (one object per line). Example:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "table": "foo"}
{"c": 3, "d": 4, "table": "bar"}
{"a": 5, "b": 6, "table": "foo"}
...
```

I want to parse the contents of text files into Spark DataFrames based on the table name. So in the example above, I would have a DataFrame for "foo" and another DataFrame for "bar". I have made it as far as grouping the lines of JSON into lists inside of an RDD with the following (pyspark) code:

```
text_rdd = sc.textFile(os.path.join("/path/to/data", "*"))
tables_rdd = text_rdd.groupBy(lambda x: json.loads(x)['table'])
```

This produces an RDD containing a list of tuples with the following structure:

```
RDD[("foo", ['{"a": 1, "b": 2, "table": "foo"}', ...],
    ("bar", ['{"c": 3, "d": 4, "table": "bar"}', ...]]
```

How do I break this RDD into a DataFrame for each table key?

edit: I tried to clarify above that there are multiple lines in a single file containing information for a table. I know that I can call .collectAsMap on the "groupBy" RDD that I have created, but I know that this will consume a sizeable amount of RAM on my driver. My question is: is there a way to break the "groupBy" RDD into multiple DataFrames without using .collectAsMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split it efficiently into parquet partitions:

First we'll convert it into dataframe:

```py
text_rdd = sc.textFile(os.path.join("/path/to/data", "*"))
df = spark.read.json(text_rdd)
df.printSchema()
    root
     |-- a: long (nullable = true)
     |-- b: long (nullable = true)
     |-- c: long (nullable = true)
     |-- d: long (nullable = true)
     |-- table: string (nullable = true)
```

Now we can write it:

```py
df.write.partitionBy('table').parquet([output directory name])
```

If you list the content of `[output directory name]`, you'll see as many partitions as there are distinct values of `table`:

```py
hadoop fs -ls [output directory name]

    _SUCCESS
    table=bar/
    table=foo/
```

If you want to keep each table's columns only, you can do this (assuming the full list of columns appear whenever the table appears in the file)

```py
import ast
from pyspark.sql import Row
table_cols = spark.createDataFrame(text_rdd.map(lambda l: ast.literal_eval(l)).map(lambda l: Row(
        table = l["table"], 
        keys = sorted(l.keys())
    ))).distinct().toPandas()
table_cols = table_cols.set_index("table")
table_cols.to_dict()["keys"]

    {u'bar': [u'c', u'd', u'table'], u'foo': [u'a', u'b', u'table']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. Map each text string to json.

   ```
   jsonRdd = sc.textFile(os.path.join("/path/to/data", "*")).map (.....)
   ```
2. Get all distinct table names to driver.

   ```
   tables = jsonRdd.map(<extract table name only from json object >).distinct().collect()
   ```
3. Iterate through each (step 2) tables and filter main jsonRdd to create rdd for individual table.

   ```
   tablesRDD=[]
   for table in tables:
        # categorize each main rdd record based on table name.
        # Compare each json object table element with for loop table string and on successful match return true.
       output.append(jasonRdd.filter(lambda jsonObj: jsonObj['table'] == table))
   ```

I am not python developer so exact code snippet might not work as is.